# How to dynamically show further information with jQuery and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

I have list of courses from MySQL and when I click the course it should display the correct course description to the right and again when I click the next course, the previous should hide and get the current click course description, Here is the code I did

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $("#toggle_value").click(function(){
          $("$courseid").show("slow");         
        });
     });
```

PHP Code

```
$cour = get_records_sql('SELECT c.id, c.summary FROM mdl_course c');
echo '<table style="background:white;border:2px solid blue">';
foreach($cour as $cou) 
{
   $coursename = $cou->fullname;
   $summary = $cou->summary;                          
   echo '<tr style="border:1px solid #BACC82;">
            <td><div class="toggle_button"><a href="javascript:void(0);"   
                  id="toggle_value">'.$coursename.'</a></div></td></tr>
<div id="div1" style="display:none;top:440px; border:0px solid #000;float:right;background-color:white; padding:5px;">
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: JavaScript (and therefore jQuery) works on the rendered HTML, ***not*** the server-side script. Please edit the question to incorporate a sample of the relevant HTML in order that we can answer.

Comment: This is because PHP is server side, when you assign a value to your $coursedesc and $coursename variables until you refresh the page (or reload via Ajax) all your variables will be the same (only one value). So you need either use Ajax technique or get all possible values to a variable and use by splitting in Javascript part..

Comment: Hi David and Alper, Thank you for your response                               Now I tried to edit the question, Could you please suggest now

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference PHP variables in jQuery - jQuery is browser side and PHP is server side.

What you could is is update the click function to load the data on click :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#toggle_value").click(function(){
         $('#<target div>').load('<url of php file>', {courseid : ##});       
    });
 });
```

The php file you put inplace of `<url of php file>` returns the data for the course you click. The data you pass will be available in php using `_POST['courseid']` You will need to add the course id into the `#toggle_value` anchor - but you could add this as any attribute.

Here is a full example - **untested** and you will **need** to update somethings such as file names and table columns :

getAllCourses.php :

```
$courses = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT c.name,c.id FROM mdl_course c');
echo '<table>';
foreach($courses as $course) 
{                         
   echo '<tr><td><a href="#" rel="'. $course['id'] .'" class="toggle_value">'.$course['name'].'</a></td></tr>
}
echo '</table><div id="coursesummary"></div>';
```

getCourse.php :

```
$courseid = mysql_real_escape_string(_GET['courseid']);
$course = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT c.summary FROM mdl_course c where c.id = $courseid'));
echo $course['summary'];
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".toggle_value").click(function(){
         $('#coursesummary').load('getCourse.php?courseid=' + $(this).attr('rel'));       
    });
 });
```

Comment: It says illegal character
[Break On This Error] $.load('index.php', {courseid : ##}, '#<target div>');

Comment: Your doing to need to update the course id with a number and also replace `<target div>` with the id of the div you want the content to appear in

Comment: @user1067018 I have added a full example - its **untested** but should give you the idea of what you need to do ...

Comment: Hi Manse,This is the error Iam getting - $.load is not a function
[Break On This Error] $.load('index.php?courseid=' ...tr('rel'), '#coursesummary');

Comment: @user1067018 updated my answer - the `load()` method is just that - not a global function.

Answer (score 0):

Because of we don't know exactly what are your codes we canot advice spesific solutions. 
But ManseUK gave a proper way to you should follow. But if you want to use Ajax technique via JQuery (I mean getting information dynamically from your server as JSON data) you can [check out this tuttorial.](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/json-data-jquery-php-mysql/)

Even there are many tuttorial [on the web](http://www.google.com/search?q=get%20data%20mysql%20JQuery%20post&oq=get%20data%20mysql%20JQuery%20post)